# Cannot pass mongo/express data to react

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express

I was trying to pass my data from mongodb/express to react using `componentDidMount()` life cycle function but for some reason it doesn't work but instead it gives me this `"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"` error.

Here's how I set up my express:

```
app.get('/movies', function(req, res){
  movie.find({}, function(err, allMovies){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(allMovies);
    }
  }) 
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('App server is listening to 3000');
});
```

And inside my react file I call the componentDidMount function which is running via webpack at port 8080.

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('test')
  fetch('/movies')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(movies => this.setState({
      movies: movies
    }));
}
```

when i console.log response it returns this https://prnt.sc/iye6kk.

Any idea what am I doing wrong why my data is not passing properly?

Answer (score 1):

In `componentDidMount`,script is parsing the response  to JSON.

```
.then(response => response.json())
```

But server is not  sending the response in the JSON format.

Send it in json format.

```
res.json({allMovies}); //ecma6 shorthand property names
```

Or

```
res.json({allMovies : allMovies});
```

Comment: The same thing. Same error. Do i need to run both the express server and the webpack server to both 8080? cause right now express is on 3000 while react is no 8080

Comment: @TonyBeatty not needed.Just make sure after backend changes,restart the server or simply use nodemon at backend to start server.

Comment: I restarted both the webpack (port 8080) and express server (port 3000) but still got the same error.

Comment: @TonyBeatty could you please check header response "content-type" value

Comment: this is for express /movies: http://prntscr.com/iyfgqq and here's what i see on react http://prntscr.com/iyfhbe

Comment: @TonyBeatty /movies request header not having `application/json` in content type.So,you are getting response in nonjson format.Please response header as well for the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167862/discussion-between-tony-beatty-and-riyaj-khan).